# How terminate the Tic Tac Toe game when someone already won (Using Tkinter)

Tags: python, tkinter

Since I wanted to learn GUI in Python, I coded Tic Tac toe game using the Tkinter. Everything working fine,
But - I cannot figure out following 2 instructions to code.

1. Display a message when game is tie when nobody won.
2. Terminate the game when someone won.

I already tried many different methods but didn’t success. Appreciate if somebody can guide me on this issue.
See below the codes,

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import messagebox

#Common Variables
current_player="X"
p1=[]
p2=[]
Winner=None
still_game_is_on = True

#Play board

gui_board = tk.Tk()
gui_board.title("Tic Tac Toe")

#Taking button input
button1 = tk.Button(text = " ")
button1.grid(column=0, row=0, ipadx= 40, ipady=40)
button1.config(command = lambda : Button_result(1))

button2 = tk.Button(text = " ")
button2.grid(column=1, row=0, ipadx= 40, ipady=40)
button2.config(command = lambda : Button_result(2))

button3 = tk.Button(text = " ")
button3.grid(column=2, row=0, ipadx= 40, ipady=40)
button3.config(command = lambda : Button_result(3))

button4 = tk.Button(text = " ")
button4.grid(column=0, row=1, ipadx= 40, ipady=40)
button4.config(command = lambda : Button_result(4))

button5 = tk.Button(text = " ")
button5.grid(column=1, row=1, ipadx= 40, ipady=40)
button5.config(command = lambda : Button_result(5))

button6 = tk.Button(text = " ")
button6.grid(column=2, row=1, ipadx= 40, ipady=40)
button6.config(command = lambda : Button_result(6))

button7 = tk.Button(text = " ")
button7.grid(column=0, row=2, ipadx= 40, ipady=40)
button7.config(command = lambda : Button_result(7))

button8 = tk.Button(text = " ")
button8.grid(column=1, row=2, ipadx= 40, ipady=40)
button8.config(command = lambda : Button_result(8))

button9 = tk.Button(text = " ")
button9.grid(column=2, row=2, ipadx= 40, ipady=40)
button9.config(command = lambda : Button_result(9))


#Handling players
def Button_result(position):
    global current_player
    if current_player == "X":
        include_to_Layout(position, "X")
        p1.append(position)
        current_player = "O"
    elif current_player == "O":
        include_to_Layout(position, "O")
        p2.append(position)
        current_player = "X"

    winner()
    if Winner == 1 or 2:
        result()
    else:
        Tie()

    return position

#Buttin outputs
def include_to_Layout(position, Player):
    if position == 1:
        button1.config(text= Player)
        button1['state']='disabled'
    elif position == 2:
        button2.config(text = Player)
        button2['state']='disabled'
    elif position == 3:
        button3.config(text = Player)
        button3['state']='disabled'
    elif position == 4:
        button4.config(text=Player)
        button4['state']='disabled'
    elif position == 5:
        button5.config(text=Player)
        button5['state']='disabled'
    elif position == 6:
        button6.config(text=Player)
        button6['state']='disabled'
    elif position == 7:
        button7.config(text=Player)
        button7['state']='disabled'
    elif position == 8:
        button8.config(text=Player)
        button8['state']='disabled'
    elif position == 9:
        button9.config(text=Player)
        button9['state']='disabled'

# Check the winner
def winner():
    global Winner
    if ((1 in p1) and (2 in p1) and (3 in p1)):
        Winner = 1
    elif ((1 in p2) and (2 in p2) and (3 in p2)):
        Winner = 2
    elif ((4 in p1) and (5 in p1) and (6 in p1)):
        Winner = 1
    elif ((4 in p2) and (5 in p2) and (6 in p2)):
        Winner = 2
    elif ((7 in p1) and (8 in p1) and (9 in p1)):
        Winner = 1
    elif ((7 in p2) and (8 in p2) and (9 in p2)):
        Winner = 2
    elif ((1 in p1) and (4 in p1) and (7 in p1)):
        Winner = 1
    elif ((1 in p2) and (4 in p2) and (7 in p2)):
        Winner = 2
    elif ((2 in p1) and (5 in p1) and (8 in p1)):
        Winner = 1
    elif ((2 in p2) and (5 in p2) and (8 in p2)):
        Winner = 2
    elif ((3 in p1) and (6 in p1) and (9 in p1)):
        Winner = 1
    elif ((3 in p2) and (6 in p2) and (9 in p2)):
        Winner = 2
    elif ((1 in p1) and (5 in p1) and (9 in p1)):
        Winner = 1
    elif ((1 in p2) and (5 in p2) and (9 in p2)):
        Winner = 2
    elif ((3 in p1) and (5 in p1) and (7 in p1)):
        Winner = 1
    elif ((3 in p2) and (5 in p2) and (7 in p2)):
        Winner = 2

#Display the winner
def result():
    if Winner == 1:
        messagebox.showinfo(title="Congratulation.", message = "Player 1 is the winer")
    elif Winner == 2:
        messagebox.showinfo(title="Congratulation.", message="Player 2 is the winner")

gui_board.mainloop()
```

Comment: What is the Tie function?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. See [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). We cannot effectively help you until you post your MRE code and accurately specify the problem. We should be able to paste your posted code into a text file and reproduce the problem you specified.
Dumping your entire code for a localized problem is not acceptable.  Hard-code the two conditions you want to handle, and post your attempted solution to each.

Comment: `gui_board.destroy()` to close main window and end program.

Answer (score 0):

1)
use a for-loop to go through all button check if its state is disabled

2)
try

```
system.exit(0)
```

Comment: Hi many thanks for the response. However, the issue is someone can win before all the buttons get disabled.

Comment: yes, so check if return value of winner is None or number, if it is none and all button is disabled, then we can assume the game ends with no winner